# How to hold text file's data into variable and read/display it on php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, text-files

I make a website on php and want to read some information from text file. the reason is if, i want to update connection string, data base name, hyperlinks,echo messages etc. then i don't want to update my php code i just replace that text in text file and the relative changes reflects in php file.

For example,

**1. A php file :**

```
    <?php
    $servername = "Server_Name";   //Comes from db_config.txt file
    $username = "User_Name";       //Comes from db_config.txt file
    $password = "Password";        //Comes from db_config.txt file

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Conn_Succ_Msg";    //Comes from db_config.txt file
    ?>
```

**2. A text file like : (db_config.txt)**

```
    Server_Name = localhost
    User_Name = abc
    Password = 123
    Conn_Succ_Msg = Connected successfully
```

I study "PHP 5 File Open/Read/Close" from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp but not getting how to implement this even if it possible in xml file, etc also fine. Or can it possible with java scripts,  jquery etc. Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple task like that I would use file() function:

```
$config = file("db_config.txt");
```

So, you will get an array with a cell for each line. Then you can parse:

```
foreach ($config as $parameter)
{
     $ar = explode(" = ", $parameter);
     $$ar[0] = $ar[1];
}
```

Note that the assignment of "$$ar[0]" has two $$: this will create a new variable which name will be the content of $ar[0]. This way you will have all your parameters as variables with the same name ($Server_Name, $User_Name, etc).

Then, your final script:

```
$config = file("db_config.txt");

foreach ($config as $parameter)
{
     $ar = explode(" = ", $parameter);
     $$ar[0] = $ar[1];
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($Server_Name, $User_name, $Password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo $Conn_Succ_Msg;
```

Thus, this is not the best way to do it. You should create a .php file with all your parameters defined as PHP variables and then include it, like this:

example db_config.php:

```
$Server_Name = 'localhost';
$User_Name = 'abc';
$Password = '123';
$Conn_Succ_Msg = 'Connected successfully';
```

Then add at the head of your PHP script:

```
include('db_config.php');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($Server_Name, $User_name, $Password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo $Conn_Succ_Msg;
```

This is safer, because you do not risk that someone can access your file directly by URL, if you set wrong file permissions.

Comment: But, how i assign values to servername, etc. i just confused in foreach loop. can you please give an example ?

Comment: I put a better explanation in the answer about the double $$ assignment.

Comment: I added a pseudocode to explain better the final result

Comment: thanks for explanation i am trying to implement the code but due to my more lines of code gettings some errors. the second way as you suggest is safe and easy.

Comment: Yes, in your shoes I would go with include() solution

Comment: I choose this as an answer because of second solution is safe and easy to implement and i solve my problem. because of both solutions give same results. Now i open db_config.php file in notepad make some edits and save thats all !

Answer (score 3):

try it :

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen("db_config.txt", "r");
$ser = array();
$i = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
  $ser[$i] = fgets($file_handle);
  $i++;
}
fclose($file_handle);
$servername = $ser[0];
$servername = explode("=", $servername);
$servername = trim($servername[1]);

$username = $ser[1];
$username = explode("=", $username);
$username = trim($username[1]);

$password = $ser[2];
$password = explode("=", $password);
$password = trim($password[1]);

$Conn_Succ_Msg = $ser[3];
$Conn_Succ_Msg = explode("=", $Conn_Succ_Msg);
$Conn_Succ_Msg = trim($Conn_Succ_Msg[1]);

$servername = $servername;
$username = $username;
$password = $password;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo $Conn_Succ_Msg;

?>
```

open file and get line and expload line with = and trim for remove spaces .

also you can using expload and trim in while :

```
$file_handle = fopen("db_config.txt", "r");

$ser = array();
$i = 0;
while (!feof($file_handle)) {

    $ser[$i] = fgets($file_handle);
    $sers = explode("=", $ser[$i]);
    $ser[$i] = trim($sers[1]);
    $i++;
}

fclose($file_handle);

$servername = $ser[0];
$username = $ser[1];
$password = $ser[2];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo $ser[3];
```

Comment: Why those tautological assignments "$servername = $servername", "$username = $username" and "$password = $password"? :)

Comment: ha ha ha , its easy for beginner php developer .

Comment: @hasan movahed i implement above code but getting Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in $servername = trim($servername[1]);